# NG-Table not working with nested data structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-structures, web-applications, libraries

I am trying to use the NG-Table library to display data to users in a web-app I'm creating, but it seems that the built in functions are not able to sort data structured like this:

```
var data = [
{
generalInfo:{
    name: "Morty",
    age: 20
}
},
    {
generalInfo:{
    name: "Ricky",
    age: 20
}}];
```

The actual database I am using requires the data to be structured like this, so I can not change the structure. I tried changing my HTML to match this format, but the filter element does not allow dot notation.

My html looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="appController as vm">
    <table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table table-bordered table- striped table-condensed" show-filter="true">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td title="'Name'" filter="{ generalFeatures.name: 'text'}" sortable="'generalFeatures.name'">{{user.generalFeatures.name}}</td>
            <td title="'Age'" filter="{ generalFeatures.age: 'number'}" sortable="'generalFeatures.age'"> {{user.generalFeatures.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Is there any way for me to sort data structured this way?

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution to this problem. I could create new properties in the parent object by looping through all of the properties in the nested object and adding them to the parent.

```
angular.forEach(data, function (user) {
    if(user.generalInfo != null){
        user.age = user.generalInfo.age;
        user.name = user.generalInfo.name;
    }
});
```